# Regex c# involving digit and spaces

Tags: c#, .net, regex

What does the following Regex do?

```
    \d{1,3}.?\d{0,3}\s[0-9a-zA-Z. -]{4,40}
```

I understand d is for digit but what does 1,3 do.

If somebody can explain further as well that would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{n,m}` is a quantifier which means "at least n times, at most m times". Like all quantifiers, it is greedy by default, and for regex dialects which support them, it also has lazy and possessive versions (`{n,m}?` and `{n,m}+` respectively -- .NET supports the former but not the latter, unfortunately).

If `n` is not specified, it is 0; if `m` is not specified, it is infinity.

This means you can "rewrite" the classical `*`, `+` and `?` using this quantifier:

- `*` is `{0,}`;
- `+` is `{1,}`;
- `?` is `{0,1}`.

(note: I think the `.` in `.?` was meant to be a literal dot, which means it should be escaped, that is `\.?`; the dot in a regex means "any character", except in a character class.)

As to the regex itself:

```
\d{1,3}        # match a digit, one to three times, followed by
.?             # any character, 0 or one time (see my remark), followed by
\d{0,3}        # a digit, zero to three times, followed by
\s             # a space character, followed by
[0-9a-zA-Z. -] # a digit, or any letter, or a dot, or a space, or a hyphen,
{4,40}         # 4 to 40 times
```

Finally, it should be noted that `\d` in .NET languages does not limit itself to 0-9, it can match other Unicode digits.

edit: the regex, fixed, taking into account @AlanMoore's comment, would be:

```
\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3})?\s[0-9a-zA-Z. -]{4,40}
```

Maybe this regex should be anchored, too... But this is a guess only.

Comment: I think you're right about the dot.  In fact, I think it and the second group of digits are meant to be the optional fraction part of a real number, so the digits should not be present unless the dot is (and vice versa): `\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3})?`

Comment: @AlanMoore good point... I suspected it too, but lacking context it is guess play ;) I think you're right, though.